# Timer stops in the background : Android

Tags: android, service, timer, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using a timer in my application for repeated task. By default, the `timer` should repeat the task with a delay of one second. I am starting the timer when the application Starts. All this is works perfectly. Also,When I came out of my application  and open some other application, the timer keeps running.

When I open Google Maps application, my timer stops running. I don't know why this is happening. I  googled and found from the activity life cycle that, if other applications needs memory, all processes will be killed. This is what happening in my case, I guess.

I do not want my timer to stop. It must run always till the user uninstall my application.

1. Why the above problem occurs?
2. How to achieve my requirement?
3. Does Using `services` will solve the problem? If so, Is there any way to keep `timer` always ON without using `services`?
4. Does Alarm Manager be helpful? Even if the user restarts the phone, the timer should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a service will solve your problem. The persistence of an Activity is governed by its lifecycle, so in the end, you have no control of its execution. A service is persistent in that it will not be shut down by the system. If you are doing extensive calculation, however, be warned that the OS will not be as generous with resource allocation as it is with an on-screen activity.

In short:

1) Well, from the information you've given, I suppose you drew the right conclusions.

2) Through a service.

3) Yes, it will solve your problem, no, I don't think there is another way to do that, at least not from within an activity.

4) If you're not actually asking about the persistence of a Java.util.Timer but for a way to have a piece of code executed at certain times, this might be the better (/easier) solution. I don't know how well it works for rather frequent timings, though. A service can be resumed on system restart, so no worries about phone shutdown. You can subscribe to the startup event.